# php recursive zip?

Tags: php, zip

Currently FTP is insanely slow on our server when it comes to multiple small files.

I am wanting to create a file that I can run in my browser that creates a zip file.

Basically this file will sit in /htdocs

The zip file it creates must take all files in /htdocss (and sub folders ect) and mimic the structure.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I am attempting to use the below code.

The only issue is that,
I am getting some blank folders

say the file is:

`C:/xampp/htdocs/booking/zip.php`

I get
/C
/C/xampp
/C/xampp/htdocs
/C/xampp/htdocs/booking
/C/xampp/htdocs/booking/image.png
/C/xampp/htdocs/booking/index.php

I dont want `/C/xampp/htdocs/booking`

I just want the zip file to contain 
image.png
index.php

How can I fix this?

```
<?php

function Zip($source, $destination) {
  if(extension_loaded('zip') === true) {
    if(file_exists($source) === true) {
      $zip = new ZipArchive();

      if($zip->open($destination, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) === true) {
        $source = realpath($source);

        if(is_dir($source) === true) {
          $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($source), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

          foreach($files as $file) {
            $file = realpath($file);

            if(is_dir($file) === true) {
              $zip->addEmptyDir(str_replace($source . '/', '', $file . '/'));
            } else if(is_file($file) === true) {
              $zip->addFromString(str_replace($source . '/', '', $file), file_get_contents($file));
            }
          }
        } else if(is_file($source) === true) {
          $zip->addFromString(basename($source), file_get_contents($source));
        }
      }

      return $zip->close();
    }
  }

  return false;
}

Zip(dirname(__FILE__), 'testzip.zip');
?>
```

Comment: Windows or *NIX? While PHP has native ZIP support, it's probably easier to just invoke the OS' `zip` command if available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options. You can use PHPs built-in [ZipArchive](http://php.net/manual/de/class.ziparchive.php) and manually iterate over the directory contents (readdir or DirectoryIterator).

Or you can do the lazy thing:

```
header("Content-Type: archive/zip");   // mime 2.0
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=dir.zip");
passthru("zip -q -r - .");
```

Depends on the installed `zip` tool. It complains if you try that on the terminal, but should work over the passthru pipe.

Comment: @Hailwood: Look into the error.log, your provider probably has no `zip` installed. You could use `"tar -cz ."` instead (adapt mime type), if you have a decent zip tool on your PC.